# Optimal Control Singular Arcs

Tags: control-engineering, optimal-control

This is about linear time-invariant, stationary problems.

According to Donald Kirk's book *Optimal Control Theory*, for minimum-fuel problems on page 299, I was told that if there exists a singular arc, then the controllability matrix is singular or the system matrix $A$ is singular. However, the controllability matrix being singular (or the system matrix $A$ being singular) does not imply a singular arc's existence, according to [this source on MIT OCW.](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-323-principles-of-optimal-control-spring-2008/lecture-notes/lec10.pdf)

On the other hand, for minimum-time problems, on page 296, the system is controllable *if and only if* there are no singular arcs (it is also mentioned by the MIT OCW lecture notes). How can one mathematically prove these?

I have seen the proofs of singular arcs being the sufficient condition, but how can one prove that it's a necessary condition for minimum-time (but not for minimum-fuel)?

Comment: I’ve solved many minimum time problems that have no singular arcs. From what I understand, minimum fuel problems *can* have singular arcs but that’s because the control has a bang-bang structure.

Comment: Hmmm ok. Do you know the general proofs of what I asked, though?